# can i reproduce a video/flv radio station stream with javascript and flash?

Tags: javascript, android-audiomanager

i am trying the soundmanager http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/demo/api/ to play a radio online, but i am having some problems... i see in the console that i am getting the stream, but its never played...

Here my sample code:

```
var fortyeight = soundManager.createSound({
  url: 'http://stream.timlradio.co.uk/ABSOLUTECRIRAACS?type=.flv'
});

if (!fortyeight.loaded) {
  // first time loading/playing
  fortyeight.load({
    stream: false,
    onload: function() {
      // sound has fully-loaded
      this.play();
    }
  });
} else {
  // sound has already loaded
  fortyeight.play();
}
```

Any clues?